# I fell asleep and zuhr finished

Tags: salat, salat-qada

I can't remember  exactly what happened but I think I were sitting down waiting for someone to get out of the bathroom so I could do wudu so I can pray Zuhr? I was in my room right near my bed so I just decided to jump in my bed. One thing may have led to the next and I woke up after during Asr prayer. I think I may have been quite tired. What do I do now? Shall I pray Zuhr namaz with Asr namaz or shall I pray Zuhr with the intention that I overslept?

Answer (score 2):

You should pray your prayers! Missing to pray them on time is no excuse for not praying them especially if you are aware of that or once you remember it!

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "If anyone forgets a prayer he should pray that prayer when he remembers it. There is no expiation except to pray the same." Then he recited: "Establish prayer for My (i.e. Allah's) remembrance." (20.14). ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:597))

This means if you wake up at 'Asr time and missed Dhuhr and you have enough time before the beginning of the time for Maghrib it is highly recommended to pray in order Dhuhr first and 'Asr. Ibn Hajar quoted that imam Malik even considers keeping the order as essential in such a case: This means no matter if you would miss praying 'Asr on time or not you must pray Dhuhr then 'Asr then eventually Maghrib.

Comment: What exactly does it mean by "there is no expiation except to pray the same"?

Comment: @WhyNahEh that's IMO clearly explained in my commentary on that hadith under the quote. If you missed dhuhr you must pray dhuhr etc.